# ZeroMQ installation error on MAMP with PHP 7.0.0

Tags: php, mamp, zeromq, failed-installation

I'm having a problem with the final steps of a ZeroMQ installation after running this command to install ZeroMQ with MAMP...

```
sudo pecl install zmq-beta

Build complete.
Don't forget to run 'make test'.

running: make INSTALL_ROOT="/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootIN0Z6M/install-zmq-1.1.3" install
Installing shared extensions:     /private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootIN0Z6M/install-zmq-1.1.3/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/
running: find "/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootIN0Z6M/install-zmq-1.1.3" | xargs ls -dils
10893452   0 drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel    102 21 Apr 11:29 /private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootIN0Z6M/install-zmq-1.1.3
10893999   0 drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel    102 21 Apr 11:29 /private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootIN0Z6M/install-zmq-1.1.3/usr
10894000   0 drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel    102 21 Apr 11:29 /private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootIN0Z6M/install-zmq-1.1.3/usr/lib
10894001   0 drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel    102 21 Apr 11:29 /private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootIN0Z6M/install-zmq-1.1.3/usr/lib/php
10894002   0 drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel    102 21 Apr 11:29 /private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootIN0Z6M/install-zmq-1.1.3/usr/lib/php/extensions
10894003   0 drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel    102 21 Apr 11:29 /private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootIN0Z6M/install-zmq-1.1.3/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226
10894005 168 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  82396 21 Apr 11:29 /private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootIN0Z6M/install-zmq-1.1.3/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/zmq.so

Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/zmq.so'
ERROR: failed to write /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/zmq.so (copy(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/zmq.so): failed to open stream: Operation not permitted)
```

I've been through a bunch of issues to get this far, but am really not sure what could be the cause of this "operation not permitted".  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use sudo ... its saying not permitted

Comment: I already was - see the first line of the output I posted

Answer (score 1):

You need install pecl on PHP from MAMP first(not on PHP CLI) and then run command bellow:

```
sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/bin/pecl install zmq-beta
```